# Word for sharing an old experience with someone new

Tags: word-choice, american-english, loanwords

*Jamais vu* is when an experience that is old to you suddenly seems new.  But I'm looking for something even more specific.  Is there a word for that feeling you get when an old experience is refreshed by sharing it with someone new?  For example, watching a favorite movie with someone who's never seen it, and enjoying it vicariously through their reactions.

Comment: I'd add *nostalgia*, but it's not always a pleasant experience, so I'm adding it in case I look back on this question and ponder what might have been, had I submitted it as an answer.

Comment: Since you specifically mention "refreshed by sharing", *rekindled interest* came to mind. But, the "vicarious" connotation eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common idiom to express this feeling in English is to experience it "***again, for the first time***".

Google's Ngram viewer shows [this phrase has been in popular use since at least the early 1800s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=again%20for%20the%20first%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,again%20for%20the%20first%20time;,c0), and has enjoyed steadily increasing popularity since then.

Since this is a phrase, instead of an atomic unit like *jamais vu*, it's a bit more flexible, and you could extend it to mean the fresh sensation is due to the company of another person, simply by extending it: "*again, for the first time, **with you***".

Comment: As a child of the 80s, I first encountered that phrase in the advertising slogan for a product I can't even remember.  It's seemed tacky ever since.

Comment: Oh, it's definitely tacky. And vapid. But I'm not the who will be saying it to my new girlfriend when we're watching *The Princess Bride* for the first time together ;)

Comment: *We meet again. For the first time, for the last time*... Also, don't forget about [Foreigner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=os0F4-XFf6w)

Answer (score 1):

[Relive:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Relive)  may describe the feeling of rejoicing  an old experience again through the excitement of another person:

> - to experience again, as an emotion.
> - to experience (a sensation, event, etc) again, esp in the imagination.

Comment: I think idiomatically, *relive* is typically associated with unpleasant experiences and memories.

Comment: It has no negative connotation. 'Relive positive experiences' vs 'relive negative experiences' in Google Fight shows 95k vs 61k. http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=relive+positive+experiences&word2=relive+negative+experiences

Comment: That google fight is unlikely to be representative (think "relive the war" vs "relive our wedding day" and innumerable other potential phrases). Turning to references: *live through (an experience or feeling, **especially an unpleasant one**) again in one's imagination or memory. "he broke down sobbing as he relived the attack"*

Comment: Well, pls produce 'representative' evidence if you want to support what you are saying. Personal opinions are welcome anyway!! :). Moreover, 'again,  for the first time' may well refer to an unpleasant experience as well'.

Comment: I thought I had? The definition I quoted is verbatim from Googling "define relive". Here's another link with the same text: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/relive (no, that's not the real OED; I don't have a subscription to that).

Comment: I am sorry, but my link above shows the definition in three different dictionaries and none of them refers explicitly to 'unpleasant events' in their definitions. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: @DanBron is correct that "relive" usually carries a negative connotation but that connotation is quickly removed in the appropriate context. The most common positive example is "relive the glory days."

Answer (score 0):

[reminisce](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reminisce), although it's more often used for discussion with others who shared the experience, the definition seems to include telling new people.

> To recollect and tell of past experiences or events.

Comment: Either way, it's about discussion, not experiencing the repetition itself.